# In MvvmCross how do I do custom bind properties

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using `MvxBindableListView` to bind a `List<>` of data objects to a `ListView`. The layout I am using for the rows has several `TextView`s. I am successfully binding the `Text` property for each of these to a property in my data object, but I have found that I cannot bind to `TextColor` as that property does not exist in Mono For Android `TextView`s; instead you have use the `SetTextColor()` method. So how can I bind a data object property to a method?! Below is the code I tried to use:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MyValueTextView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        local:MvxBind="
        {
          'Text':{'Path':'MyValue','Converter':'MyValueConverter'},
          'TextColor':{'Path':'MyOtherValue','Converter':'MyOtherConverter'}
        }" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an example of adding a custom 2-way binding for "IsFavorite" in the Conference sample - see:

- the binding - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Droid/Bindings/FavoritesButtonBinding.cs
- the binding setup in `FillTargetFactories` in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Droid/Setup.cs

This example is explained a bit further in: [MVVMCross Bindings in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495137/mvvmcross-bindings-in-android)

For a one-way "source-to-target" custom binding, the code should be a bit simpler - you only need to handle the `SetValue` - and don't need to invoke `FireValueChanged` in any event handling code.

---

For textColor, I'd imagine the binding would look a bit like:

```
public class MyCustomBinding
    : MvxBaseAndroidTargetBinding
{
    private readonly TextView _textView;

    public MyCustomBinding(TextView textView)
    {
        _textView = textView;
    }

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        var colorValue = (Color)value;
        _textView.SetTextColor(colorValue);
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(Color); }
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
    }
}
```

and would be setup with:

```
    protected override void FillTargetFactories(MvvmCross.Binding.Interfaces.Bindings.Target.Construction.IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);

        registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<TextView>("TextColor", (textView) => new MyCustomBinding(textView)));
    }
```

Note: I've not compiled this example code - when you do get it working, please come back and correct this pseudo-code :)

Comment: To be honest, we just cut and paste the code exactly as it is and it just worked - not bad for pseudo code! ;)

Comment: If you are building these samples inside some sort of SuperSimpleBinding thing, then it would be fab if you could GitHub it :) - assuming GitHub is now a verb :) It would be useful for your internal training as well as for public mvx information too :)

Comment: Could you give me a clue, how I should deal with the similar situation on Touch and in case I would want to deals with such binding not relatively some property but Action (for instance, like "Button onclick")? I've found MvxTargetBinding class to inherit from, but the situation with event/action handling/binding is not fully clear for me. Thanks!

Comment: i am also interested to know the same in iOS (touch). can you please help me?

Comment: Both of your code links point to a 404, any chance you could update this answer?