# Take/Select picture and show it in ImageView without saving first (using MvvmCross)

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I want to choose a picture from library or take a picture with the camera and show the result to the view (ImageView)

But according to a few posts including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475896/need-an-example-of-take-a-picture-with-monodroid-and-mvvmcross), the MvxHttpImageView I use needs a Uri to show the image (wheter it comes from file systemor camera). This implies, converting the Stream into a file and getting the Uri back.

I wrote a Picture Service that does the job:

```
public class PictureService : IPictureService, 
    IMvxServiceConsumer<IMvxPictureChooserTask>, 
    IMvxServiceConsumer<IMvxSimpleFileStoreService>
{
    private const int MaxPixelDimension = 1024;
    private const int DefaultJpegQuality = 92;

    public void TakeNewPhoto(Action<string> onSuccess, Action<string> onError)
    {
        this.GetService<IMvxPictureChooserTask>().TakePicture(
            PictureService.MaxPixelDimension,
            PictureService.DefaultJpegQuality,
            pictureStream =>
            {
                var newPictureUri = this.Save(pictureStream);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newPictureUri))
                    onSuccess(newPictureUri);
                else
                    onError("No picture selected");
            },
            () => { /* cancel is ignored */ });
    }

    public void SelectExistingPicture(Action<string> onSuccess, Action<string> onError)
    {
        this.GetService<IMvxPictureChooserTask>().ChoosePictureFromLibrary(
            PictureService.MaxPixelDimension,
            PictureService.DefaultJpegQuality,
            pictureStream =>
            {
                var newPictureUri = this.Save(pictureStream);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newPictureUri))
                    onSuccess(newPictureUri);
                else
                    onError("No photo taken");
            },
            () => { /* cancel is ignored */ });
    }

    private string Save(Stream stream)
    {
        string fileName = null;
        try
        {
            fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            var fileService = this.GetService<IMvxSimpleFileStoreService>();
            fileService.WriteFile(fileName, stream.CopyTo);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            fileName = null;
        }

        return fileName;
    }

}
```

But for privacy reason, I do not want to save the picture on filesystem. The workflow is:

1. Take or select picture
2. Show it on screen (with additional info)
3. Save my model on server sending image to the cloud: not trace on the
   device

My question is: how can I handle the Streams containing picture data without saving on filesystem?

Or

How to use a temporary storage system that is not accessible to user (ignore "rooted" device case)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try creating your own custom `ImageView` control:

**1.** Use a `MemoryStream` to collect the received `pictureStream` into a `byte[]` property on the ViewModel, e.g. `MyBytes`

```
pictureStream => {
     var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
     pictureStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
     TheRawImageBytes = memoryStream.GetBuffer()
}
```

where `TheRawImageBytes` is:

```
private byte[] _theRawImageBytes;
public byte[] TheRawImageBytes
{
    get { return _theRawImageBytes; }
    set { _theRawImageBytes = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => TheRawImageBytes); }
}
```

**2.** Create your own `MyImageView` class derived from `ImageView`, add the `(context, attr)` constructor, then expose a `byte[]` property on the `MyImageView` - when that `byte[]` is set then use `BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray` and `SetBitmap` to render the picture from the incoming bytes

```
private byte[] _rawImage;
public byte[] RawImage
{
     get { return _rawImage; }
     set 
     {
             _rawImage = value;
             if (_rawImage == null)
                     return;

             var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(_rawImage, 0,_rawImage.Length);
             SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
     }
}
```

**3.** Use `<yourapp.namespace.to.MyImageView ... />` in the axml instead of the normal `<ImageView ... />`

**4.** In the axml bind the View `byte[]` property to the source ViewModel `byte[]` property.

```
local:MvxBind="{'RawImage':{'Path':'TheRawImageBytes'}}"
```

**5.** That's it - although you might want to add some error handling and do some testing

---

This approach is adapted from the answer to [MvvmCross Android Bind Image from byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194546/mvvmcross-android-bind-image-from-byte)

As mentioned in that question, an alternative approach would be to use a standard `ImageView` with a custom binding instead.

---

For more on creating custom views/widgets based on standard views/widgets - including on how to replace `<yourapp.namespace.to.MyImageView ... />` with an abbreviation `<MyApp.MyImageView ... />`, see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/creating-custom-views-is-easy-to-do.html

Comment: I'll use the Custom ImageView solution which will be more flexible for further evolutions and UI goodness. But the custom Binding is pretty straight forward and worked for me in a blink of an eye. Thanks a lot @Stuart for that complete answer.