# MvvmCross custom binding via INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've got similar situation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700445/in-mvvmcross-how-do-i-do-custom-bind-properties), but in Touch. Trying to deal with that via INotifyPropertyChanged though.

My code is the following:

```
set.Bind(txtSearch).For(x => x.Text).To(x => x.SearchText);
```

where txtSearch is my custom wrapper of UISearchBar. So, I *can not inherit* from *MvxNotifyPropertyChanged* as I already inherit from *UIView* (the wrapper is view).

Text property is:

```
 public string Text { get
    {
        return _search.Text;
    } set
    {
        _search.Text = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Text);
    }
}
```

and I fire it on the SearchBar text changing (which works).

I've also added the following:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected IMvxMainThreadDispatcher Dispatcher
    {
        get { return MvxMainThreadDispatcher.Instance; }
    }

    protected void InvokeOnMainThread(Action action)
    {
        if (Dispatcher != null)
            Dispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(action);
    }
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
    {
        var name = this.GetPropertyNameFromExpression(property);
        RaisePropertyChanged(name);
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string whichProperty)
    {
        var changedArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(whichProperty);
        RaisePropertyChanged(changedArgs);
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs changedArgs)
    {
        // check for subscription before going multithreaded
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
            return;

        InvokeOnMainThread(
            () =>
            {
                var handler = PropertyChanged;

                if (handler != null)
                    handler(this, changedArgs);
            });
    }
```

But when everything gets to RaisePropertyChanged, then I see that PropertyChanged is empty (so, seems no code is subscribed for my object). Which, of course, makes no notifications further.

I have similar situation but with some object inherited *directly* from MvxNotifyPropertyChanged, which seems working fine. Does that mean, that MvvmCross only can deal with such objects but not ones which generally use INotifyPropertyChanged?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is used on the ViewModel side for property changes.

On the View side, MvvmCross uses `DependencyProperty` bindings on Windows, and C# methods, properties and events on the Xamarin platforms.

`INotifyPropertyChanged` isn't provided by default on the View side - since no off-the-shelf View objects support `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then there was no point in trying to bind to it within any of the MvvmCross View platforms.

However, the binding system is extensible - so if anyone wants to write `INotifyPropertyChanged` based views and wants to include a custom `INotifyPropertyChanged` binding for the View side, then they can do that following the steps similar to [In MvvmCross how do I do custom bind properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700445/in-mvvmcross-how-do-i-do-custom-bind-properties) and following examples linked from https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/custom-bindings-in-mvvmcross

If they want to write an `INotifyPropertyChanged`-based system for the View side, then I'm sure this could be achieved using a custom binding approach - but it's not something I've personally done. I would expect such a custom binding to work both for `INotifyPropertyChanged` and for `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged` too (since `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`) - but I guess it would be up to the author to decide on the mechanics of that.