# MVVMCross binding to badgevalue

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to bind to the badgevalue of a TabBarItem like this:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
set.Bind(ViewControllers[0].TabBarItem.BadgeValue).To(vm => vm.MyNumber);
set.Apply();
```

but I get the following error:

```
MvxBind: Error:   6.30 Empty binding target passed to MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry
```

However if I set the value directly like this the badge appears:

```
ViewControllers[0].TabBarItem.BadgeValue = ((MyViewModel)ViewModel).MyNumber;
```

Why is the binding not working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because you need to set up your own binding extensions if what you are trying to bind to doesn't exist as a valid binding target already.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700445/in-mvvmcross-how-do-i-do-custom-bind-properties) where Stuart answered a similar question for Android.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. For ios I found this presentation about custom bindings on ios [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=taBoOenbpiU&t=1673s)

Answer (score 1):

**Create a custom binding:**

```
public class TabBadgeBinding : MvxTargetBinding
{
    public const string TargetPropertyName = nameof(TabBadgeBinding);

    private readonly UIViewController _viewController;

    public TabBadgeBinding(UIViewController viewController) : base(viewController)
    {
        _viewController = viewController;
    }

    public override Type TargetType => typeof(UIViewController);

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode => MvxBindingMode.OneWay;

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        if (value is string badgeValue)
        {
            _viewController.TabBarItem.BadgeValue = badgeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

**Register Binding in `Setup.cs`:**

```
    protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
        registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<UIViewController>(TabBadgeBinding.TargetPropertyName, (controller) => new TabBadgeBinding(controller)));
    }
```

**Use Binding in your VC:**

```
    set.Bind(ParentViewController).For(TabBadgeBinding.TargetPropertyName).To(vm => vm.UnreadNotificationsCount);
```