# How do I bind TextStyle using MVVMCross?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'd like to bind the TextStyle property of a TextView using the If-Else ValueCombiner in Android. I tried the following, but it fails to create the binding:

`<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="MyText"
            local:MvxBind="TextStyle If(ShowBold, 'bold', 'normal')" />`

I tested similar binding with the Text property and it worked fine, so I guess it's looking for something other than a string?

Comment: You will most likely have to use a ValueConverter, since you can't pass in Android types through strings in bindings.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: @AaronBratcher I just did it, check below.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but I had the same requirement and just did it now.

Add the following in your setup file (I have two custom bind properties, **Style** and **Summary**):

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);

    registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<TextView>("Style", textView => new StyleTextViewBinding(textView)));
    registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<TextView>("Summary", textView => new SummaryTextViewBinding(textView)));
}
```

In my TextView (my custom binding is **Style** obviously, **Text** and **TextColor** are converters):

```
<TextView
    style="@style/TeamDifficulty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/dummy_title"
    local:MvxBind="Text TeamDifficultyText(RowItem.DifficultyEnumCaptain1Int); TextColor TeamDifficultyTextColor(RowItem.DifficultyEnumCaptain1); Style RowItem.DifficultyEnumCaptain1;" />
```

And the actual code (basically it checks if my text is empty or not, if it is, it will bold it since my converter will add a value to it after):

```
public class StyleTextViewBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    readonly TextView _textView;

    public StyleTextViewBinding(TextView textView) : base(textView)
    {
        _textView = textView;
    }

    #region implemented abstract members of MvxConvertingTargetBinding
    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        _textView.SetTypeface(_textView.Typeface, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Bold);            

        if (value != null && Convert.ToBoolean(value))            
            _textView.SetTypeface(_textView.Typeface, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Normal);                
    }
    #endregion

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(bool); }
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example of text color that Stuart helped someone else with.  [In MvvmCross how do I do custom bind properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700445/in-mvvmcross-how-do-i-do-custom-bind-properties)

Using that you should be able to reverse engineer a way to do this for a text style.