# Binding OxyPlot via MVVMCross in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, oxyplot

I have added `OxyPlot` Android and Core in my `Xamarin` PCL based project where I am using `MVVMCross`.

I have added the plotview in my xml as follows. But I do not know how to bind this view using MVVMCross.

Is there any good example or resources to follow?

**MyView.xml**

```
<oxyplot.xamarin.android.PlotView
android:id="@+id/plot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**MyView.cs**

```
public class MyView : MvxFragment<MyViewModel>
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.MyView, null)

        MyViewModel MyMainViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        var a = view.FindViewById<PlotView>(Resource.Id.plot);
        a.Model = MyViewModel.MyModel;

        return view;
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public PlotModel MyModel { get; set; }
public MyViewModel
{
  PlotModel mo = new PlotModel();
  var s1 = new LineSeries()
  {
    Color = OxyColors.SkyBlue,
    MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
    MarkerSize = 6,
    MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White,
    MarkerFill = OxyColors.SkyBlue,
    MarkerStrokeThickness = 1.5
  };
  s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 10));
  s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10, 40));
  s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(40, 20));
  s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(60, 30));
  mo.Series.Add(s1);
  MyModel = mo;
}
```

---

Additional Information for OxyPlot installation

I have added OxyPlot as follows through Package Console.

**In the PCL**

```
PM> Install-Package OxyPlot.Core -Version 1.0.0-unstable1983 -Pre
```

**In the Android**

```
PM> Install-Package OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android -Pre
```

Or you can also add them in Nuget Console from prelease library.

Comment: You probably should do a custom binding for this and each time the model gets changed (RaisePropertyChanged()) , you invalidate the bound OxyPlot. Atleast by roughly looking at this. 
I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700445/in-mvvmcross-how-do-i-do-custom-bind-properties could help you, since you should only need a One-Way binding. If you need more help, i will try to make a example.

Comment: I have deleted and rebuilt the code that I posted, it has worked like a charm.But if you could help me out with the following related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332858/oxyplot-in-recyclerview-mvvmcross-xamarin-android , it would be so helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want using standard Mvx property binding. No custom binding required.

Example based on question:

**Approach 1: Fluent binding**

*ViewModel*

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        GeneratePlotPoints();
    }

    void GeneratePlotPoints()
    {
        var mo = new PlotModel();
        var s1 = new LineSeries()
        {
            Color = OxyColors.SkyBlue,
            MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
            MarkerSize = 6,
            MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White,
            MarkerFill = OxyColors.SkyBlue,
            MarkerStrokeThickness = 1.5
        };
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 10));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10, 40));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(40, 20));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(60, 30));
        mo.Series.Add(s1);
        MyModel = mo;
    }

    PlotModel _myModel;
    public PlotModel MyModel
    {
        get { return _myModel; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _myModel, value); }
    }
}
```

*View/Layout*

```
<oxyplot.xamarin.android.PlotView
   android:id="@+id/plot"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

*Fragment/Code Behind*

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.MyView, null);

    var graphControl = view.FindViewById<PlotView>(Resource.Id.plot);

    var bindset = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
    bindset.Bind(graphControl).For(c => c.Model).To(vm => vm.MyModel);
    bindset.Apply();

    return view;
}
```

**Approach 2: Xml Binding**

*ViewModel*

Same as above

*View/Layout*

```
<oxyplot.xamarin.android.PlotView
   android:id="@+id/plot"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   local:MvxBind="Model MyModel"/>
```

*Fragment/ Code behind*

No binding code needed, just make sure to run the layout through the binding inflater.

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.MyView, null);
}
```

Comment: @PlaceHolder, `<oxyplot.xamarin.android.PlotView
` is one of the subview in the `MyView.xml`, I did not put all xml components, I only put oxyplot.. how do you handle/bind only oxyplot? I am asking, because I dont see the following  in your solution `view.FindById(Resource.Id.plot)`?

Comment: @hotspring, you are 100% right, I added the missing graphControl `FindById`

Comment: Was just thinking the CustomBinding for the Invalidation of the Chart, since i wasnt sure how Oxyplot handles it. But nice!