# OxyPlot in RecyclerView -MVVMCross Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, oxyplot

I have the following implementation where I have recycler view, in each view I am trying to display a data using OxyPlot.

I could able to see hard coded Plotvalues on the each card, but when I scroll, it is kind of a slow response and app freezes a while. I wonder what I am doing wrong or how to improve this performance issue?

**MainView.xml**

```
<MvxRecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
  android:divider="@null"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/mycardview" />
```

**mycardview.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <oxyplot.xamarin.android.PlotView
       android:id="@+id/Plot"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainView.cs**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
   var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.MainView, null);
   HasOptionsMenu = true;
   var cardRecyclerView = view.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.myRecyclerView);
   if (cardRecyclerView != null)
   {
       cardRecyclerView.HasFixedSize = false;
       cardRecyclerView .Adapter = new MainViewRecyclerAdapter((IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext, Activity);
       var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity);
       cardRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

  return view;
}
```

**MainViewRecyclerAdapter .cs**

```
public class MainViewRecyclerAdapter : MvxRecyclerAdapter
{

  private readonly FragmentActivity _activity;
  public MainViewRecyclerAdapter(IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext, FragmentActivity activity)
        : base(bindingContext)
  {
      _activity = activity;
  }

  public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
  {
      base.OnBindViewHolder(holder, position);

      var view = holder.ItemView;
      var cardOptionsButton = view.FindViewById<PlotView>(Resource.Id.Plot);
      MainViewModel MyMainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
      cardOptionsButton.Model = MyMainViewModel.MyModel;
   }
}
```

**MyMainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        GeneratePlotPoints();
    }

    void GeneratePlotPoints()
    {
        var mo = new PlotModel();
        var s1 = new LineSeries()
        {
            Color = OxyColors.SkyBlue,
            MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
            MarkerSize = 6,
            MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White,
            MarkerFill = OxyColors.SkyBlue,
            MarkerStrokeThickness = 1.5
        };
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 10));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10, 40));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(40, 20));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(60, 30));
        mo.Series.Add(s1);
        MyModel = mo;
    }

    PlotModel _myModel;
    public PlotModel MyModel
    {
        get { return _myModel; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _myModel, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your "sAll" list look like in your ViewModel? You should just be able to use XML binding simliar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316666/binding-oxyplot-via-mvvmcross-in-xamarin-android/38336559#38336559, but based off of the model from your list.

Comment: I have updated my question with working example, but now I have performance issue. When I put each plot on each card and scroll them, it is slow. I wonder where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to get your example from the question to work. However, what you can try is to use binding for the data (Plot points) to your layout, rather than re-constructing your `ViewModel` as a standard class object in your `Adapter`.

---

**Implementation Example:**

**ViewModel**

For simplicity I have just created a simple `ObservableCollection` which contains the same groups of plot points (graph shape) repeated a few times. ***UPDATE:*** As a [`PlotModel` can only be used once in an `PlotView`](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/pull/780) you have to make sure that `PlotModel` is always a new instance.

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    PlotModel GeneratePlotPoints()
    {
        var mo = new PlotModel();
        var s1 = new LineSeries()
        {
            Color = OxyColors.SkyBlue,
            MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
            MarkerSize = 6,
            MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White,
            MarkerFill = OxyColors.SkyBlue,
            MarkerStrokeThickness = 1.5
        };

        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 10));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10, 40));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(40, 20));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(60, 30));
        mo.Series.Add(s1);

        return mo;
    }

    List<PlotModel> GenerateGraph()
    {
        var graphPlots = new List<PlotModel>();
        int counter = 0;

        while (counter < 10)
        {
            graphPlots.Add(GeneratePlotPoints());
            counter++;
        }

        return graphPlots;
    }

    public List<PlotModel> GraphPlots => GenerateGraph();
}
```

**Layout**

Your main layout with the RecyclerView.

```
<MvxRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource GraphPlots"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/mycardview" />
```

The `mycardview` layout template. Note that the use of the point is used to tell Mvx to bind to the whole model (in this case the PlotModel) but it also can be left blank ([Mvx doc link](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/data-binding#section-swiss)).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <oxyplot.xamarin.android.PlotView
     android:id="@+id/Plot"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     local:MvxBind="Model ."/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**View**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
   var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.MainView, null);
   HasOptionsMenu = true;
   var cardRecyclerView = view.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.myRecyclerView);
   if (cardRecyclerView != null)
   {
       cardRecyclerView.HasFixedSize = false;
       var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity);
       cardRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    return view;
}
```

---

***Update - Include screenshot***

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the effort and furthermore for crystal clear explanation.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Comment: @Placeholder, I have just got a chance to test your solution but for some reason nothing shows up. Have you tested?

Comment: It seems to me that `local:MvxBind="Model ."` is not working. did you add `Custom Bindings` ? If yes, could you please also include it?

Comment: nope, there is no custom binding, `Model` is the model property on the `PlotView` control. Are you perhaps trying to bind to something other than a `PlotModel`? Are there perhaps issues in the output window?

Comment: Have you run the solution and able to see the plots? I could able to see `GraphPlots` have 10 items and I properly declared the layout template in the resources/layout folder, as as you suggested I did not use `RecyclerAdapter`. I exactly copied your solution but no luck.

Comment: I have updated post to show screenshot of graphs. Are you getting any errors/warnings in the output window?

Comment: is it possible to share your solution please, like github? I have redone everything still no luck.

Comment: @hotspring, you can check out the [GitHub sample](https://github.com/Plac3hold3r/OxyPlotMvxExample), the OxyPlot stuff can be found in the HelpAndFeedback section. Hope it helps.

Comment: That is awesome and I have figure out the root of my issue.

Comment: When I have a fragment on the top of the plot activity and when I click back button, the plot does not show anything. do you have anything in your mind?

Comment: @hotspring, check out the updated [GitHub sample](https://github.com/Plac3hold3r/OxyPlotMvxExample). Was getting ["This PlotModel is already in use by some other PlotView control"](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/pull/780) in output window. It relates to a [plot model](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot/PlotModel/PlotModel.cs#L785) having a 1 to 1 relationship with the plot view. So we have to create a new model each time.

Comment: Could you please let me know the changes in your recent github.? I could not able to find in the github history.