# MvvmCross binding to multiple properties on android control using swiss syntax

Tags: android, binding, mvvmcross

What is the correct syntax for binding to multiple properties on an Android element?

I tried something like this `local:MvxBind="{ Value StartTime, Text StartTimeText}"`

where properties StartTime and StartTime text are defined in the ViewModel but this does not work. Value and Text are properties of this custom control.

The ViewModel may look like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public DateTime StartTime{get;set;}
   public string StartTimeText {get;set;}
}
```

I found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688603/how-do-i-bind-multiple-properties-in-an-android-layout-element), but cannot find the correct Swiss syntax for multiple bindings. Any one done multiple bindings on an element?

TIA.

Comment: Can see an example of multiple bindings here: https://medium.com/@casseykeating/mvvmcross-value-converters-2dbd0259fb78

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Syntax I was looking for is:

> local:MvxBind="Value StartTime; Text StartTimeText"

Don't forget the space after the ";". Without it you won't get the first binding.

Comment: For more on syntax, you can also read https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding

Comment: i can not see anything about the verbs (Value,Text) in the wiki ?

Comment: and combining on the same line with ; does not work :(